# Shiny: How to prevent input duplicates when rendering outputs?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

In the following example, duplicate input elements seem to be created, although `output$app` is re-rendered with every login/logout.

```
library(shiny)

user <- reactiveValues(logged_on = 0)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("app")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    if (user$logged_on == 1) {
      output$app <- renderUI({
        list(
          uiOutput("container1"),
          uiOutput("container2")
        )
      })
      output$container1 <- renderUI({
        actionButton("logout", "Logout")
      })
      output$container2 <- renderUI({
        actionButton("clickme", "Click Me")
      })

      observeEvent(input$clickme, {
        print("got clicked!")
      })

      observeEvent(input$logout, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
        user$logged_on <- 0
      })

    } else {

      output$app <- renderUI({
        actionButton("login", "Login")
      }) 

      observeEvent(input$login, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
        user$logged_on <- 1
      })

    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Clicking `Login` followed by `Click Me` prompts `got clicked!` once. However, after repeating the process by `Logout`>`Login`>`Click Me` prompts the message twice, and so on.

Examining this problem using...

```
      x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
      print(x)
```

...confirms that duplicates of the input elements are created. Why does this happen and how do i prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you have observeEvents within your observe. This isn't necessary and I've edited your code and now the duplicates seem to have been removed. (Also the ignoreInits were unnecessary here.)

```
library(shiny)

user <- reactiveValues(logged_on = 0)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("app")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    observe({
        if (user$logged_on == 1) {
            output$app <- renderUI({
                list(
                    uiOutput("container1"),
                    uiOutput("container2")
                )
            })
            output$container1 <- renderUI({
                actionButton("logout", "Logout")
            })
            output$container2 <- renderUI({
                actionButton("clickme", "Click Me")
            })

        } else {

            output$app <- renderUI({
                actionButton("login", "Login")
            }) 

        }

    })

    observeEvent(input$clickme, {
        print("got clicked!")
    })

    observeEvent(input$logout, {
        user$logged_on <- 0
    })

    observeEvent(input$login, {
        user$logged_on <- 1
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem :) I still don't understand why this happened though. Any ideas?

Comment: All I can think is it has something to do with the observeEvent within an observe. Some recursive business I'm guessing...

Answer (score 1):

So I've found that nesting `observeEvent()` within each other, registers new observers and that caused the problem. A better example than my previous one is:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("clicks", "Click"),
  actionButton("more_clicks", "Print")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$clicks,{
    observeEvent(input$more_clicks, {
      print("Hello") # you can see these piling up in the console when switching buttons
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My guess is that this should be avoided when possible, although `observeEvent()`'s can be nested if the child observer is destroyed after it has gotten triggered. This can be accomplished by the argument `observeEvent(eventExpr, handlerExpr, once = TRUE)`.